# Проблемы с кодировкой в плагине таксономии modx revo

Tags: php, modx, администрирование

Вся админка отображается нормально, установил плагин Taxonomies [ссылка на модуль Taxonomies](https://modx.com/extras/package/taxonomies) внес категории и вот так они отображаются, картинка прикреплена. Везде на сайте кодировка стоит utf-8 и в файле .htaccess. и в базе. 
Подскажите как сделать нормальное отображение пожалуйста.
[image]

Comment: Судя по скриншоту отображается win1251 в UTF8. Видимо исходный текст сохранён не в UTF8 а в Win1251. Поправить можно либо сохранив текст в правильной кодировке, либо перед выводом конвертировать в нужную кодировку.

Comment: Где можно поменять кодировку название ресурса?
Так как термины берутся из названия ресурсов.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте расширение UTF-8, у вас win1251

Comment: О каком конкретном расширении идет речь?

В системных настройках modx_charset стоит UTF-8

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Может кто-то еще ищет и мой ответ пригодится:
Для нормального отображения русского языка в плагине "Taxonomies" необходимо убрать функцию кодирования в utf8 перед преобразованием в json в строках 81 и 97 http://joxi.ru/Q2K0y3nF443lOA